# React js crashes after re render with different child elements number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In react.js I need component which render 'tr' with one or two 'td', depend of its property. Here is example:

```
  var Item = React.createClass({

    content: function() {
       if(this.props.n==1) {
         return [<td calSpan={2}> Colspan</td>]
       }

       if(this.props.n==2) {
         return [<td> Td-1</td>, <td> Td-2</td>]
       }
    },

    render: function() {
            return (<tr> {this.content()}</tr>);
    }
    });
```

This component renders fine once. After changing propery, react js try re render and crash with error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined react.js:1079 ) (in Chrome). But in jsfiddle its works fine. Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbazylev/x5p3C/9/ (click on table for re render). If you copy code from jsfiddle and execute it in browser, code would be crashed.

I find some workaround. Replace

```
 return [<td calSpan={2}> Colspan</td>]
```

to

```
  return [<td calSpan={2}> Colspan</td>, <td></td>]
```

Its not valid html, but it works. Why this error occurs? How can it be solved in another (better) way?

Comment: Also fiddle is using react 0.4.  Current is 0.10.  Might be why it works there.

Comment: What is `calSpan`? Do you mean `colSpan`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an extraneous space in your `tr` element; change

```
<tr> {this.content()}</tr>
```

to

```
<tr>{this.content()}</tr>
```

React renders the spaces as `span` elements, but because `tr` elements can only contain `td` elements, the browser sticks them outside of the table:

[image: Document Inspector Screenshot]